# What's wrong with this implementation of piping?

Tags: c, unix, process, operating-system, posix

I would like to know what is wrong with this implementation of piping. I am trying to implement the following command `ls |grep "main-pipe" |wc`. However, it gets into infinite loop and I don't understand why it doesn't read from the standard input. I have also checked whether the output from `ls` is correctly obtained in the second process(for `grep`) is correct and it was correct. I can't figure out what causes the infinite loop. Could you please help me with that?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    printf("Please don't provide additional arguments.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  int pipe1[2];
  pipe(pipe1);

  int pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    // Write to the write end of the pipe
    close(1);
    dup(pipe1[1]);
    close(pipe1[1]);
    close(pipe1[0]);
    execlp("ls", "ls");
  }
  wait(0);

  int pipe2[2];
  pipe(pipe2);

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    close(0);
    dup(pipe1[0]);
    close(pipe1[0]);
    close(pipe1[1]);

    close(1);
    dup(pipe2[1]);
    close(pipe2[0]);
    close(pipe2[1]);
    execlp("grep", "grep", "main-pipe", (char *)NULL);
  }
  wait(0);

  close(0);
  dup(pipe2[0]);
  close(pipe1[0]);
  close(pipe1[1]);
  close(pipe2[0]);
  close(pipe2[1]);

  execl("wc", "wc");

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: In `execlp("ls", "ls")` you still need to terminate the argument list with a `NULL` pointer. Same when you execute `wc`. And there's no need to cast `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Good uses of `dup()` are rare.  If you want to dupe onto a specific file descriptor number (as here you do) then use `dup2()`.

Comment: The problems are likely your `wait(0)` calls.  They will block the parent process while waiting for the child process to finish. And it's not certain that the child processes exits when you think they do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, one *does* need to cast `NULL` when using it as a variable argument to a variadic function such as `execlp()`.  That covers not only the possibility that `NULL` is defined as `0`, but more generally the fact that different pointer types are not (in general) compatible.

Comment: I have tried with `dup2` versions, still the problem persists

Comment: It's not an "infinite loop".  `grep` is blocked on a read, waiting for all ends of the pipe to be closed.

Comment: @WilliamPursell as you can see all ends are closed

Comment: @ErikNouroyan, they are not closed until *after* the original process waits for the `grep` process to terminate.  Meanwhile, `grep` does not see EOF on its input because the write end of that pipe is still open in the original process.  Overall, someprogrammerdude's comment is most on point: the two `wait(0)` calls are not merely useless here, but actively harmful.  Even if they didn't break the program, the idea of a pipeline is that the processes within run in parallel, but your `wait()`s attempt to serialize them.

Comment: Doesn't `grep` process have its copy of the pipe's fd's, I mean aren't they closed in the `if` statement before calling `exec`? Could you please clarify what's wrong with `wait()`s. I can't understand how this can run in parallel if the first process should end for the second one to have the output of the previous one as an input?

Comment: The first process *does not* need to terminate for the second one to (start to) use its output as input.  The analogy to plumbing inherent in the name "pipe" is apt. Bytes emitted by the first process become available immediately for the next to read, similar to water flowing through a pipe.

Comment: OK, and what if the parent process ends earlier, won't those child processes terminate and the output be invalid or not present?

Comment: Termination of the parent process will not cause termination of its children.  Unexpected termination of the parent or of any of the children might indeed cause data to be truncated or otherwise fail to meet expectations, but that is not solved by the parent `wait()`ing on the children.  Or by any other means, really.  Sometimes bad data happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that really helped me a lot to learn some more details about processes, removing the `wait()`s resolved the problem.

Comment: Keep in mind that `exec` family of functions including `execl` replace the currently running process with a new process.  It never returns if successful, so the `  exit(0);
` will never be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it gets into infinite loop and I don't understand why it doesn't read from the standard input.

An infinite loop is not the only reason for failing to make progress.  There's no reason to think that any process is failing to attempt to read from its standard input.  In this case, in fact, attempting to read from the standard input is exactly what prevents the `grep` process from making progress.

You have performed the redirections correctly, though as I noted in comments, this is among the many cases where `dup2()` would be a better choice than `dup()`.

The primary issue is your `wait(0)` calls.  These are semantically inappropriate, because they interfere with one of the key characteristics of a shell-style pipeline, that the participating processes run in parallel, each consuming the output of the previous more-or-less as it is produced.  More importantly, however, the `wait()`s cause a practical issue for you, amounting to an inter-process deadlock.

You need to appreciate several things:

- A process operating as a UNIX-style filter reads and processes data from its standard input until it detects end-of-file.  Typically, such a process emits its results to its standard output, allowing multiple such processes to be composed.  `grep` works this way when reading from its standard input.
- EOF is observed on the read end of a pipe only after all copies of the write end of that pipe have been closed.  Until then, readers can never be confident that there won't eventually be more data to read.
- Each process has its own file descriptors, but multiple processes can all have their own file descriptors that refer to the same underlying open file description.  The numeric values of those FDs sometimes are the same, but they don't need to be.  Such multiple references to the same open file description especially happen as a result of file descriptors being duplicated across a `fork()`.

Now consider how that all plays out for your program.

1. The parent sets up a pipe whose ends are stored in `pipe1`.
2. It forks two children, one to run `ls` and the other to run `grep`.  Each of these inherits copies of the parent's file descriptors for the pipe ends.

   - I'm ignoring the first `wait()` here.  If `ls`'s output were very long then this `wait()` could cause a problem, with the pipe's buffer filling to capacity and therefore preventing `ls` from finishing.  But that's unlikely to be what's actually happening in your case.
3. Each child performs appropriate redirection.  The `ls` redirects its standard output into the write end of the pipe, and the `grep` redirects is standard input from the read end of the pipe.
4. Each of those children closes *its own excess copies* of the file descriptors for the ends of that pipe.  At this point, however, **the parent still has open file descriptors for both ends of that pipe**.
5. When the `ls` terminates, all its open file descriptors are closed automatically.  This is what ordinarily would allow the `grep` process to observe EOF on its standard input, and therefore to itself terminate.  That does not happen in your program, however, because the parent still has an open file descriptor for the write end of that pipe.
6. Meanwhile, the parent is blocked at the second `wait()`.  Like the previous `wait()` this one could be an issue strictly in and of itself if `grep` produced large enough output to fill the buffer of the pipe to which its output is connected.  That's moot in this case, however, because the parent defers closing its copies of the `pipe1` file descriptors until after the `wait()` returns, while at the same time, the `grep` process cannot terminate normally until the parent closes the write end of that pipe.  Neither process can make progress once the `grep` has consumed all the output from `ls` -- they are deadlocked.

You could solve this particular deadlock by having the parent close at least the write end of pipe1 as soon as it forks the second child, at which point the parent has no further use for that pipe anyway.  Closing unneeded pipe ends as soon as possible is good programming practice, verging on essential.  But eliminating the `wait(0)` calls is necessary anyway to avoid other issues that I've touched on, and doing that would be sufficient to allow the parent to perform all its necessary pipe-end closures soon enough to resolve the deadlock.